# Android view zip file without extracting

Tags: java, android, zip

I am trying to get the contents of a zip file without extracting it. I am using ZipFile to get the entries. But what I observed is it is giving all the files in zip folder in file format like system/app.apk instead of giving system as a directory(like how file.listFiles() gives). How do i get the files in a directory structure format?

**Zip structure:**

```
   ZipFolder.zip - system (folder) -> app.apk(file)

                 - meta (folder) -> manifest(folder) -> new.apk (file)
```

Code:

```
  ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(mPath);
  Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();  
      while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
          // below code returns system/app.apk and meta/manifest/new.apk
          // instead of system,meta folders 
          ZipEntry entry  = entries.nextElement();  
          String fileName = entry.getName();
          boolean isDirectory = entry.isDirectory(); //returns false
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following method (see below) to retrieve a file listing of a zip file.

Please take note:

- Directory Names are used as Keys.
- Filenames are stored in an `List<String>` for a specific Directory Name.
- If a file is not stored within a directory, we add to a default `root` key.

---

```
public HashMap<String, List<String>> retrieveListing(File zipFile) {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> contents = new HashMap<>();
    try  {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                String directory = ze.getName();
                if (!contents.containsKey(directory)) {
                    contents.put(directory, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
            } else {
                String file = ze.getName();
                int pos = file.lastIndexOf("/");
                if (pos != -1) { 
                    String directory = file.substring(0, pos+1);
                    String fileName = file.substring(pos+1);
                    if (!contents.containsKey(directory)) {
                        contents.put(directory, new ArrayList<String>());
                        List<String> fileNames = contents.get(directory);
                        fileNames.add(fileName);
                    } else {
                        List<String> fileNames = contents.get(directory);
                        fileNames.add(fileName);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!contents.containsKey("root")) {
                        contents.put("root", new ArrayList<String>());
                    }
                    List<String> fileNames = contents.get("root");
                    fileNames.add(file);
                }
            }
            zin.closeEntry();
        }
        zin.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contents;
}
```